# How to apply a class randomly without to duplicate in loop?

Tags: php

I have a `loop` where I am inserting some `html` element and I need to add a `class` to it but I need this `class` to be **from 1 to 4 max**, like `gallery__item--3` or `gallery__item--1` and applied randomly **without duplicates** and avoid `gallery__item--3` and `gallery__item--3`.

Currently I do the following but I get duplicates and I am not sure how to check:

```
$min = 1;
$max = 4;
foreach( $galleria as $image ):  
  <figure class="gallery__item--<?php echo rand($min,$max); ?>">
endforeach;
```

Literally looking for:

`1,3,4,2` or `4,2,1,3`

Comment: Does the number used need to be random? Can't you just increment the number? How many images are you iterating over? If you only have 4 numbers but more than 4 images, how are you going to avoid duplicates?

Comment: @RaulSauco as per the comment I've made on the answer, that won't be random tho, I need the count to be placing random figures like 1,3,4,2 or 4,2,1,3...

Comment: You could just check if you have used that value already. I am assuming you **know** there are a max of 4 images in the gallery.

Comment: @RaulSauco yes I do know how many images, actually I have a counter which stops the loop when it reaches 4.

Comment: I was going to suggest using `array_rand(1,2,3,4)` and then removing the element,  but @msg's answer below seems like a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to avoid duplicates, I assume there are only four images.

You can use [`shuffle`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to randomize a previously created array:

```
$rands = range(1,4);
shuffle($rands);
foreach( $galleria as $image ):  
  <figure class="gallery__item--<?= array_pop($rands); ?>">
endforeach;
```

If you have more than 4 elements you can still use this approach checking if there are elements left and regenerating the array. If you need every iteration to be different you can also check that the ordering hasn't been used before (just keep in mind that there are a limited number of combinations).

```
$rands = [];
$pasts = [];

foreach( $galleria as $image ):  
    if (empty($rands)):
        do {
            $rands = range(1,4);
            shuffle($rands);
        } while (in_array($rands, $pasts)); 
        $pasts[] = $rands;
    endif;
    <figure class="gallery__item--<?= array_pop($rands); ?>">
endforeach;
```

Comment: I just tried it array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

Comment: Yes this looks great and works. But I'm not 100% that we will not have duplicates at some points since we have no reference, nowhere we're saying that the shuffle() wont' be the same per what previously created, or am I not understing it?

Comment: @rob.m Well, yes, at some point is going to return the same ordering, about 4% chance, I think.

Comment: yeah that's not ideal then, what if I just push to array the used value each time and do a check if in_array() then skip and rand again until it gets the number which isn't in array?

Comment: @rob.m with a n length array, you have a n! number of possible combinations (24 in case of 4), so yes it will start to repeat at some point

Comment: oh well i guess it's fine tho, I will accept this as it is shorter, thanks

Comment: i do unfortunately :( but that's fine, i mean, it's rare anyway, thanks

Comment: @rob.m Added checking if the order was used before. Just out of curiosity, how many elements do you have in the `$galleria` array?

Comment: @msg tbh I don't know but what I thought of doing is to put a counter for 4, if more then break, ideally I'd love not to have it tho. Basically I am creating a grid with the images like the following link, but since it uses fixed css classes I'd need to stop the counter, I was just thinking of creating a unique experience each time we land on the page, this is the grid https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-an-image-gallery-with-css-grid-e0f0fd666a5c/

Comment: @rob.m I updated the answer with your suggestion about using `in_array`, so you can have more than 4 elements (up to 96) in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

First check to see if `$galleria` has images

```php
if (count($galleria) > 0) {
    // following code will go here
}
```

Then create an array using [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) with the values:

```php
$values = range(0, count($galleria) - 1); //Assuming $galleria has 10 images, $values looks like (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Then use [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to rearrange the values:

```php
shuffle($values); //$values now looks something like (2,3,0,8,9,6,7,5,1,4)
```

**Optional**: Reduce the array to your maximum count

```php
$max = 4;
$values = array_slice ( $values , 0, $max ); //$values now looks like (2,3,0,8)
```

Finally iterate over the values:

```php
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $image = $galleria[$value]; //use this line if you need the $image from $galleria
    echo "<figure class=\"gallery__item--$value\">";
}
```

This way you don't need to store and check what has been used already or pop used values from the array.

Comment: I'm not 100% that we will not have duplicates at some points since we have no reference, nowhere we're saying that the shuffle() wont' be the same per what previously created, or am I not understing it?

Comment: `range` creates the values in order eg (1,2,3,4) and `shuffle` rearranges them randomly eg (2,1,4,3). The `foreach` loop then iterates sequentially over the shuffled array, no need to pop items.

Answer (score 0):

Updating as per comment:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foreach( $galleria as $image ):  
  $rand = rand(1, count($arr));
  $val = $arr[$rand];
  unset($arr[$rand]);
  <figure class="gallery__item--<?php echo $val; ?>">
endforeach;
```

Also, I would prefer doing it like below -

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
foreach($galleria as $image) { 
  $rand = rand(1, count($arr));
  $val = $arr[$rand];
  unset($arr[$rand]);
  echo "<figure class='gallery__item--{$val}'">
}
```

Comment: that won't be random tho, I need the count to be placing random figures like 1,3,4,2 or 4,2,1,3...

Comment: @rob.m with a n length array, you have a n! number of possible combinations (24 in case of 4), so yes it will start to repeat at some point. would you like to explain your use case so we can understand better?

Comment: just to be clear, it will never have duplicate elements in the array or the class name on the page. on different loads, it can have the same values. hope this helps

Comment: `array_rand` will return a random key, so it's "equivalent" to `rand(1, count($arr))` and avoid the selected key not existing, since `unset` doesn't reindex the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
 $min = 1;
    $max = 4;
    $num = 1;
    foreach( $galleria as $image ): 
      $num = rand($min,$max);
      if($min <= $max){
         if($num !== $min){
            <figure class="gallery__item--<?php echo $num; ?>">
         } else {
            $num = rand($min,$max);
         }
      } else {
         $min = 0;
         $min++;
      }
    endforeach;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: are you sure it won't get duplicates? Because I am having duplicates with this

Comment: That was your question: ` to be from 1 to 4 max`

Comment: it is creating duplicates, it's not saying "I have already used 2", this resets to 1, which means afterwards it gets random again and it might get the number placed before once more

Comment: In rand function you can not be sure that it want be do duplicates while you make a 4 digit random

Comment: or store tnat rand number and check before to apply, i will edit

Comment: any idea why this is never giving me 1?

Comment: only in case when `rand()` return 1

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean like this?

```
<?php

$classes = array(1,2,3,4);
shuffle($classes);

foreach ($classes as $class) {
    echo "<figure class='gallery__item--$class'>";
}
```