# Array of images without repetitions in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a lot of pictures in a directory ( more 25 pics ).
With a PHP function, I list sources of pictures in an array ( listImg[] )
With Symfony, I return this array with a render twig.

I would like have 9 random pictures in Homepage and 12 pics for the About page..

The problem is the repetition of pictures...

My PHP function:

```
public function showImgDir(): array
    {
        $dir = "assets/img/tour";

        $ext_list = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");
        $listImg = [];

        $picDir= opendir($dir);
        while ($file = readdir($picDir)) {
            if ($file === '.' || $file === '..') {
                continue;
            }
            
            $listImg[] = $dir . '/' . $file;
        }
        closedir($picDir); 
        return $listImg;
    }
```

and in Twig :

```
{% for a in 1..9 %}
    <img src="{{random(listImg)|imagine_filter('mini')}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to use do .. while with twig to avoid repetition but I don't understand how can use the 'loop'

```
{% for a in 1..9 %}
    {{ loop.index }}  
{% endfor %}
```

Can you help me please ? ( without JS solution for the moment )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply a class randomly without to duplicate in loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386745/how-to-apply-a-class-randomly-without-to-duplicate-in-loop)

Comment: Why not just shuffle the array before returning it and then use the first n elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you :)

I use shuffle(array);  before return

```
shuffle($listImg);
return $listImg;
```

and in twig :

```
{% for a in 1..9 %}
    <img src="{{listImg[a]|imagine_filter('mini')}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

it works ! :)